# How to change CreationTime.ToShortDateString() date format?

Tags: c#

Code line and output:

```
fileInfo.CreationTime.ToShortDateString();
```

And the output is for example is **`11/19/2012`** which is in this format **MM/dd/yyyy**.
How can i change the format to **dd/MM/yyyy**??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ToString(string format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) :

```
fileInfo.CreationTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```